# Writing while loop using for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop

In C++ `for` loop is same as `while` loop

```
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
    }

  int j;
  while(j<10)
   {
    cout<<" ";
    j++;
   }
```

I want to convert this `for` loop in `while` loop using MATLAB.

Comment: Why is the same for and while in C++?

Comment: I dont understand how the second code is that much different from the first? Just make 2 nested while loops...

Comment: Why would you want to convert this into a `while` loop if it works? `while` offers no built in control over a loop variable, which you obvioulsy need, so why not leave it as a for loop instead of having to code the loop variable handling yourself?

Answer (score 2):

The loops are not exactly the same as you actually... Still, I don't know matlab, but since you posted a C++ example I will assume you will be able to convert this to matlab, if it helps.

```
int i, j;
i = j = 2;

while(...) {//i condition

   while(...) { //j condition
      <...commands...>

    j++:
   }

 j = 2; //reset inner while counter to w/e value you need
 i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 2;
while i <= zoom_r -1
    j = 2;
    while j<= zoom_c -1
        ... executable code block goes here
        j = j+1;
    end
    i = i+1;
end
```

Comment: Please comment here and tell me How this loop works?